# Is game theory on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

I posted a [question](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/1446/185) about game theory concepts on the AI site, but it got closed as off-topic.

The question is within the context of reinforcement learning though, is it on-topic here?

Comment: In the context of reinforcement learning I expect it's likely to be on topic (it doesn't seem to want to show me your post unless I sign up to the beta). However, there's also economics.SE as an alternative possibility, depending on the emphasis

Comment: @Glen_b thank you, i'll take a look

Comment: math.SE also takes game theory questions

Comment: @JuhoKokkala thanks!

Comment: Consider copy-pasting your question here (if it's not too long). Then we can say if it is on-topic or not.

Comment: @amoeba thanks, I've already posted it on this site :P http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/230619/95569

Comment: @amoeba thanks for your help

Comment: Too bad there is still no answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Game theory is a part of mathematics more so than of statistics** / machine learning / data analysis (which is the scope of this site). As such, basic questions on game theory are more on topic on math.SE (1361 Qs in [game-theory], 397 in [combinatorial-game-theory], 109 in [algorithmic-game-theory]) and research-level questions are more on-topic on mathoverflow (154 Qs in [game-theory] and 119 in [combinatorial-game-theory]).

In contrast, we only have a meagre 13 Qs in [game-theory] and the tag does not even have a wiki excerpt, suggesting that nobody really takes care of it.

Your question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/230619 despite receiving three upvotes seems to be much more suited for math.SE. I have just voted to migrate it there.

---

**Update.** The post has been successfully migrated:

> Post Migrated Away to math.stackexchange.com by amoeba, gung, John, Andy, kjetil b halvorsen